# requests, urllib3 and CacheControl version downgrade to working in Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/releases
`2.0.0` - In this version, `strict` was removed.

As instructed in the link:
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7936
I went back to the previous version, being: `1.26.15`

In some of my dependencies, `cachecontrol` is being used:
https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/blob/v0.12.11/cachecontrol/serialize.py#L54

And no matter how old the `cachecontrol` version is, it always made use of `u"strict": response.strict`.
That is, no matter what version the `cachecontrol` is, internally, it will keep trying to fetch the `strict` attribute.

My problem was that, I can't install my dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7,<4"
requests = "^22.28.0"


[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
…
```

The error always appears:
[image]

Version of libraries I'm using with `pip list`:

```
Package             Version
------------------- ------------
CacheControl        0.12.11
requests            2.31.0
urllib3             1.26.15
```

Poetry version:
`Poetry version 1.1.6`

Note on `requests`:
If I use `requests="^2.28.0”`, it installs the following dependencies together:

```
Installing certifi (2023.5.7)
  • Installing charset-normalizer (3.1.0)
  • Installing idna (3.4)
  • Installing urllib3 (2.0.2)
  • Installing requests (2.31.0)
```

If I update `pyproject.toml` to `requests = "2.28.0”`, the dependencies downgrade is performed, as it forces use older version of the lib:

```
Updating charset-normalizer (3.1.0 -> 2.0.12)
  • Updating urllib3 (2.0.2 -> 1.26.16)
  • Updating requests (2.31.0 -> 2.28.0)
```

This way, it starts working, because `urllib3` still had the `strict` attribute, and `cachecontrol` doesn't break anymore.

`tool.poetry.dev-dependencies`: dependencies (some dependency, indirectly, is making use of `cachecontrol`, being necessary to limit the use of lib requests to 2.28.0, otherwise it will not work):

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
flake8 = "^4.0.1"
pre-commit = "^2.20.0"
pytest = "^7.0.0"
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
bandit = "^1.7.1"
mypy = "^0.931"
pylint = "^2.12.2"
black = "^22.1.0"
```